# Laravel keeps responding with redirects

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm working on a project using Laravel 5 (API, back end) and AngularJS (front end). I have a front end and an admin section for my app (as seen in the file structure below). I can access the front end properly but i cannot seem to access the main page of the admin section. I keep getting the message that this page has to many redirects in chrome.

All my html views and js/css/assets are in the `public` folder under their respective folder

This is my structure in my public folder of laravel

```
+---admin
|   +---dist
|   +---src
|   index.html
+---assets
+---bower_components
+---frontend
    +---dist
    +---src
    index.html
```

Laravel Routes.php

```
//Show Frontend Index.html
Route::get('/', function () {
    return File::get(public_path() . '/frontend/index.html');
});

//Show Admin Index.html
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return File::get(public_path() . '/admin/index.html');
});



Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
   //API'routes go here
});
```

I can access my index.html for the front end (which is just a single page website at the moment) and it works fine. But i cannot figure out the redirect loop issue when trying to access my admin index.html. I don't know if I've made a noob mistake but any help is gratefully accepted

Comment: Why are you `return File::get` instead of using proper views? This is pretty weird code that misses the point of Laravel. You don't need those routes at all if you're just having them serve HTML from the `public` directory - your webserver will handle those fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem lies on the fact that the path /admin/index.html falls into the /admin route rule, causing the loop. Maybe in this case what you need is a htaccess redirect? Like so:
Redirect 301 /admin /admin/index.html